# How to properly format overlapping mySQL IN and NOT IN conditions

Tags: mysql

I have the following mySQL table:

```
data
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

I would like to supply my select statement with two seperate lists

Exculde List:

```
1,4,5,7
```

Include List:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7
```

I tried the following statement:

```
Select * FROM table WHERE data NOT IN ('1,4,5,7') AND data IN ('1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
```

Expecting the following output:

```
data
2
3
6
```

But I received no results.  I realize I passed an impossible condition but I don't know how to format my query to return the expected results.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `IN (1,2,3)` and not `IN ('1,2,3')` as the former compares to individual values `1`, `2` and `3` while the latter is against the literal string `1,2,3`.

Answer (score 3):

`IN` takes a list of values, not a string that holds a delimited list of values.
Examples:

- `x IN (1, 2, 3)`
- `x IN ('a', 'b', 'c')`

Answer (score -1):

Select * FROM ( (Select * FROM table WHERE data NOT IN ('1,4,5,7') ) AS table  WHERE data IN ('1,2,3,4,5,6,7)

you try againt